cosets partition group "obviously implied" from two facts
Why do the following two facts imply that (left) cosets partition a group?

The relation defined by $a \sim b \iff a^{-1} b \in H$ is an equivalence relation.
$a \sim b \iff aH = bH$

I have always seen people say that these two facts alone makes it obvious, but I can only see it by taking additional steps. For example, it also holds that $a \sim b \iff a \in bH \iff b \in aH$, so if $c \in aH \cap bH$ then $aH = cH = bH$. But there should be a more simple explanation that doesn't take any extra steps, I just can't think of it.
I know that since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, it induces a partition on $G$. But what is the "obvious" explanation that this partition is actually the cosets?

The left coset containing an element $a \in G$ is $aH$. Thus, the second fact is precisely telling you that the partitions are the left cosets.

Yes, the frst two facts you mentioned are quite lackluster. Specifically, $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow aH=bH$ should be substituted by something along the lines of $aH={x\in G,:, a\sim x}$: then, the conclusion follows from the theorem about the duality between equivalence relations and partitions. By comparison, consider the equally true statement that $a^{-1}b\in H$ is an equivalence relation and $a^{-1}b\in H\Leftrightarrow H\cup aH=H\cup bH$, which doesn't imply that ${V\subseteq G,:, \exists x\in G, V=H\cup xH}$ is a partition of $G$.

Good point @SassatelliGiulio. If instead I defined $a \sim b \iff a \in bH$, then after showing this is an equivalence relation, $aH = {b \in G ~|~ a \sim b}$ is actually obvious, and then you're done. I'm happy with this.

I'm happy with the following modification.
If I define $\sim$ by $a \sim b \iff a \in bH$, then after showing $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, the equality
$$ aH = \{b \in G ~|~ a \sim b\} $$
is actually obvious, and then the conclusion follows. I think this is the best definition of $\sim$ to make the proof as clean as possible.
